# Python style decorator in Scala

Tags: python, scala, decorator

In Python I can do something like this:

```
def wrap(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print "args: ", args, kwargs
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print "result: ", res
        return res
    return wrapper
```

This lets me wrap any function regardless of the arguments they take. For instance:

```
In [8]: def f(thing):
    print "in f:", thing
    return 3

In [9]: wrapped_f = wrap(f)

In [10]: wrapped_f(2)
args:  (2,) {}
in f: 2
result:  3
Out[10]: 3
```

Is there a way to do something similar (write a wrapper that can be applied to any function regardless of its input/output types) in Scala?

Answer (score 3):

There is a fundamental issue here: in Scala you have to know what arguments the function should get and actually pass them so that the compiler can be sure that the types match.

Say there is `def f(a: List[Int], b: String) = ...` and `def g(args: Any*) = f(args)`. This won't compile! (`Any*` means any amount of objects with any type). The problem is that `Any*` is still only one single argument which actually is translated to one kind of `Array`.

Just to make this more clear you could think of an example situation: you have called the `wrap(f)` with some function `f(a: String, b: String)`. Then you have the output of the wrapper which would somehow accept any amount of any kind of arguments and you make the call `wrapper_f(List(1), "a")`. In this situation the `wrapper_f(...)` call should be correct but inside the wrapper the wrapped function has a completely different parameter list which can not accept a `List[Int]` and a `String`. Thus you would get the "Type Error" in runtime which should (in general) be impossible in statically typed programming languages (or at least in Scala).

Comment: Good explanation of why this can't be done directly in a statically typed language

Answer (score 3):

You could certainly do this with macros. You can convert a method call to a function with partial application:

```
object Foo {
  def bar(i: Int): Int = i + 1
}

val fn = Foo.bar _

defined object Foo
fn: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Now you have an object, in this case of type `Function1[Int, Int]`, which you can pass to a Scala macro, which would be something like this (not tested):

```
object DecoratorMacros {

  import reflect.macros.blackbox
  import language.experimental.macros

  def decorate[A <: Function](fn: A): [A] = macro decorate_impl[A]

  def decorate_impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context) = {
    import c.universe._
    val type = weakTypeOf[A]
    ...
  }
}
```

In the body of the macro, you can inspect the whole type signature of `fn: A`, which will include the arguments. You can then write code to do your desired side effects, and return a function which you can then invoke. Something like this:

```
DecoratorMacros.decorate(Foo.bar _)(42)
```

Macros are fairly involved, but I can elaborate if you think this is a path you'd like to go down.

Comment: I agree that this is a correct solution. However if your use case is not very extreme you shouldn't use anything like this. In my opinion this is about the type system of Scala and thing is that you should not be doing things like that in Scala (if it's not a very extraordinary situation).

Comment: @jubis, well I guess it depends on your requirements. Macros may be a bit tricky to implement the first time, but for the user of the macro they are seamless and can achieve effects you can't achieve otherwise

Comment: you're right. Mostly my point was that the person posing the question may not fully understand the type system of Scala since the reference to Python. For a person with that kind of a background I would not tell what you can do (using reflection) but what you should do in general.

Comment: This is interesting, although I agree with @jubis it is a bit more involved than I was hoping for. Decorators are not a very advanced Python feature so I was hoping Scala would have a similarly simple way to do the same thing. But after thinking more about it, makes sense that you wouldn't be able to touch the arguments of the wrapped function unless you modify how compilation works since you don't know their type.